# Is pixel explosion the computationally cheapest form of blur?

Tags: opengl, game-engine

As a hobby project I'm writing a game for the Dreamcast. As this computer has limited resources I'm looking for ways to get as much as possible out of the processor.

I remember UT99 used pixel explosion as a form of blur on textures (filtering?) is this because it's the least computationally intensive blur?

Comment: Do you also want to reduce the effective resolution ?  to block up each pixel neighborhood into a single aggregate valued pixel ?

Comment: Are you talking about the [not really bi-linear filtering described here](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Texturing_As_In_Unreal.shtml)?

Comment: @genpfault Yes. I would like to use some cheap form of blurring for cinematic "depth of field" without killing the frame rate. (4k guys call it "focal blur") I guess the least resource hogging way of doing this is swapping pixels in screen space. But that's just a guess.